# Unable to access recently imported SVN repository through Atlassian JIRA (403 Forbidden error)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, jira, atlassian-fisheye

I have an issue where I am unable to access a recently imported SVN repository through Atlassian JIRA admin. I imported it through an SVN dump.

There was an issue right at the very end of the import process where, when it was inspecting the directory structure, it timed out and threw an error.

Is there a way to determine if the SVN repo exists? It spent quite a while importing around 36,000 revisions so I am hoping there is something there.

When using both TortoiseSVN and SVN at the command line I get the following error:

Server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response to OPTIONS request for 'https://XXXjira.atlassian.net/svn'

I have the following repo structure:

/

/1984

/shop

/shop/branches

/shop/tags

/shop/trunk

Do I have to configure my user to access SVN? I cannot see anywhere to do this. Or do I have an issue with structure? The user I am logging in as has admin privileges.

I followed the [instructions](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AOD/Importing+Versioned+Data+into+Subversion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JIRA, you *must* have projects that are named (case-sensitive) to your SVN repo directories. For example, if you have /shop and /music as your directories in the root you must have projects named the same.